# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting [MySQL DB connection]

Tags: python

```
hostname = raw_input("Enter hostname : ")

connection = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost", user = "hawkhost_databas", passwd = "}MFkdDI6]#QX", db = "hawkhost_database")

cursor = connection.cursor ()

cursor.execute ("select User, Hostname, Password, Port from dbinfo where hostname=%s", (hostname))
```

Comment: Missing comma: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600286/python-mysql-connector-database-query-with-s-fails

Answer (score -1):

cursor.execute ("select User, Hostname, Password, Port from dbinfo where Hostname= '%s'" % d)

This fixed the issue