# mysql.connector - You have an error in your SQL syntax; near '%s' at line 1

Tags: python, mysql

I'm referencing [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html) in order to make a SELECT query to my database. However, I'm getting this error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
```

Here's the section of code with the problem:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxxx', password='yyyy',
                              host='zzzz.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
                              database='iiii')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# ...

givenUsername = 'testUser123'
checkUserAuthQuery = ("SELECT password FROM UserAuth WHERE username = %s")
userAuthInfo = (givenUsername)
cursor.execute(checkUserAuthQuery, userAuthInfo)

# ...
```

**Notes:**
- When doing an INSERT query with `%s` it works.
- Also, replacing `%s` with `'testuser123'` works.

Comment: Did you try making `userAuthInfo` a tuple instead of a string?

Comment: That worked, thanks @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. I would've never figured that out.

Comment: Well, DB-API 2.0 does specify that the second argument should be a sequence of values to substitute, so I'd say that the connector is in error for not throwing a useful exception.

Answer (score 27):

You are missing the comma to make `userAuthInfo` a tuple. Change it to :

```
userAuthInfo = (givenUsername,)
```

Comment: This should be closed either as a duplicate of one of the *many* missing comma Q/A, or as simple typo.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I tapped out the answer from my phone, so it was easier to write the answer than search for a duplicate. If you find a suitable duplicate target then I'll vote to close.

Comment: Sorry for the original tone. Here's a good candidate, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23600286/python-mysql-connector-database-query-with-s-fails . I spent my vote on "typo" already, so adding the link here for you.