# Query a mysql table for a dynamic column name and its value in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to search a mysql table for rows where the specified column has a particular value. For example, given the input string `memory=2048` it will search for the rows that have `"2048"` as the value of `memory` column and it will print them.

This is code that I have tried but it print outs nothing.

```
input = input()
tag = input.split("=")
desc = tag[1]
tag = tag[0]

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "(SELECT * FROM comp WHERE %s LIKE %s)"
val = (tag, desc)
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
res = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in res:
    print(x)
```

Secondly I tried this code to see where is the problem :

```
input = input()
tag = input.split("=")
desc = tag[1]
tag = tag[0]

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "(SELECT * FROM comp WHERE memory LIKE '2048')"
mycursor.execute(sql)
res = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in res:
    print(x)
```

It gives the desired output. So my problem is when I am trying to get the column name with %s it comes as 'memory' and It couldn't finds it, since the name of the column is memory. Is there a way to get rid of the '' chars ?

[confirmation of inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkBmw.png)

Comment: I don't see the variable `s` refering to anything?

Comment: first %s takes the value of tag which is memory in my example, the second one takes desc which is 2048.

Comment: can you try it all in one line to see if it works? `mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM comp WHERE %s LIKE %s", (tag, desc))`

Comment: Already done it, same result.

Comment: can you confirm that `tag = input.split("=")` actually outputs an array and `tag` and `desc` are strings ? Otherwise `%s` won't be replaced.

Comment: I added a ss you can see it from there

Comment: Thanks! Can you use `?` instead of `%s` ?  Not sure which library you're using, but that might work.

Comment: are you sure that `execute` takes both 1 arguments and 2 arguments as a function? I would guess not..

Comment: I am using mysql.connector only, and when i used ? it says Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement.

Comment: Yes there is no problem with execute it takes it perfectly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [mysql.connector's `execute()` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) it appears to use `%s` as placeholders for bind parameters.

So your `execute("SELECT * FROM comp WHERE %s LIKE %s", ("memory", "2048"))` call ends up running like the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM comp WHERE 'memory' LIKE '2048'
```

obviously returning 0 rows.

You need to put the literal column name into the query text before invoking `execute()`:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM comp WHERE %s LIKE %s" % (tag, "%s")
# =>  "SELECT * FROM comp WHERE memory LIKE %s"
mycursor.execute(sql, (desc, ))
```

Comment: It gives this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, you have to write it as `execute(sql, (desc, ))` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267501/mysql-connector-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-near-s-at-line-1 - updated the answer