# Insert into MySQL table with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert basic data into my MySQL table without any success yet I'm using basic tutorials as demos.

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1

**My MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE awesome (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
test varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**My Python code**

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
user="root",
passwd="pass",
database="db"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO awesome (test) VALUES (%s)"
val = ("Highway 21")
mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

Comment: Add single quotes around `%s`

Comment: That would add %s into the database, I need it to add the variable val, Highway 21.

Comment: Use `val = ("Highway 21",)`. Note the comma; it makes the right-hand side a tuple with one item inside. Without the comma, Python interprets the right-hand side as a string -- it just evaluates the expression inside the parentheses as a string.

Comment: @unutbu That solved it, thanks!

Comment: Related: [Python MySQL Connector database query with %s fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23600286/190597)

Answer (score 2):

Yes the problem arises when there is only 1 argument in val tuple. Use

> val=("Highway 21",)

Note the comma at the end.